# Overriding url helper used by form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Have this model:

```
module Car
  module Used #using mongoid so no inheretance
    field name
  end
end
```

And resource

```
namespace 'marketplace' do
  resources :items
end
```

So in view, when calling

```
= form_for(Car::Used.new) do
```

not surprising that we getting this error: undefined method `car_useds_path'

So are there any workaround to tell form_for helper to use

```
marketplace_items_path
```

?

Passing :url explicitly to form_for or creating separate resource little bit unusable I think.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually pretty easy to get what I believe you are after ...

```
= form_for Car::Used.new, url: marketplace_items_path(any_required_objects) do 
  ...
```

[form_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html)

Comment: No. Just imagine @car variable instead Car::Used.new, that can be either persisted or not.

Comment: I'm not tracking, then, what you are after. In your question, you ask "So are there any workaround to tell form_for helper to use `market_items_path`", which is what this code sample does. If this is not what you are looking for, please clarify in the OP.

Comment: so please read the last line of my question again, than you have to realize that I know about existence of :url parameter.

Comment: I saw that ... but the question then, is not clear (at least not to me). Passing the :url attribute is the way to do what you asked.

Comment: All I want is to use
= form_for(@car)

instead of 
form_for(@car, marketplace_items_path) - for new record
form_for(@car, marketplace_item_path(@car)) - for persisted record

That's all